# OpenSL on Android plays at a higher rate than it should

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, opensl

I managed to create an OpenSL context and all so that it plays sound.
But I still have a problem: I set the `samplesPerSec` for my Player to `44.100 Hz` but it actually runs at ~ `70.000 Hz`. How could one fix that?

Well I'll show you what I've done (full at [Source Code](https://github.com/fodinabor/Polycode/tree/3d29fbaa6c4e71311e9ef489e0af70e95302dc76)):

In [PolyOpenSLInterface.cpp](https://github.com/fodinabor/Polycode/blob/3d29fbaa6c4e71311e9ef489e0af70e95302dc76/src/core/PolyOpenSLAudioInterface.cpp) I'm initializing OpenSL and start enqueuing a buffer to my `SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf`.
I create the Player the following way:

```
SLDataLocator_AndroidSimpleBufferQueue lDataLocatorIn;
lDataLocatorIn.locatorType = SL_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE;
lDataLocatorIn.numBuffers = 1;

SLDataFormat_PCM lDataFormat;
lDataFormat.formatType = SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM;
lDataFormat.numChannels = POLY_NUM_CHANNELS;
lDataFormat.samplesPerSec = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_44_1; //sampling rate 44.100Hz
lDataFormat.bitsPerSample = SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16;
lDataFormat.containerSize = SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16;
if(POLY_NUM_CHANNELS > 1){
    lDataFormat.channelMask = SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT | SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT;
} else {
    lDataFormat.channelMask = SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER;
}
lDataFormat.endianness = SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN;

SLDataSource lDataSource;
lDataSource.pLocator = &lDataLocatorIn;
lDataSource.pFormat = &lDataFormat;

SLDataLocator_OutputMix lDataLocatorOut;
lDataLocatorOut.locatorType = SL_DATALOCATOR_OUTPUTMIX;
lDataLocatorOut.outputMix = mOutputMixObj;

SLDataSink lDataSink;
lDataSink.pLocator = &lDataLocatorOut;
lDataSink.pFormat = NULL;

const SLuint32 lSoundPlayerIIDCount = 2;
const SLInterfaceID lSoundPlayerIIDs[] = { SL_IID_PLAY, SL_IID_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE };
const SLboolean lSoundPlayerReqs[] = { SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE };

lRes = (*mEngine)->CreateAudioPlayer(mEngine, &mPlayerObj, &lDataSource, &lDataSink, lSoundPlayerIIDCount, lSoundPlayerIIDs, lSoundPlayerReqs);
lRes = (*mPlayerObj)->Realize(mPlayerObj, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
```

My registered callback looks like this (I take the already used buffer and write the next samples into it and enqueue the buffer again):

```
void OpenSLAudioInterface::queueCallback(SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf caller, void* pContext){
    OpenSLAudioInterface *audioInterface = (OpenSLAudioInterface*) pContext;
    if(audioInterface->buffer && audioInterface->getMixer()) {
        int16_t *out = (int16_t*)audioInterface->buffer;
        audioInterface->getMixer()->mixIntoBuffer(out, POLY_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);
        (*(audioInterface->mPlayerQueue))->Enqueue(audioInterface->mPlayerQueue, out, sizeof(int16_t)*POLY_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER*POLY_NUM_CHANNELS);
    }
}
```

So can anyone explain, why the sound is played `~2 times faster` than it should be and why the samples I need to mix to fill the buffer exceed the 44.100Hz by a factor of `~2`?
Do I need to use a circular buffer (is the one I'm using here still being used by OpenSL?)?

Thanks for every suggestions and help in advance!

Comment: `lDataFormat.samplesPerSec = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_48;` your sampling rate is 48kHz, but you said you're trying to play the audio in 44.1kHz. And another thing is from this line `lDataFormat.bitsPerSample = SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16;` - I see this is a 16 bit per sample PCM audio data. But usually `SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_8` is found in most cases.

Comment: Oh.. I edited the question as I adjusted it to 44.1 to comply with the projects default.. And shouldn't a int16_t use 16 bit? (Although I'll test it with 8bit)

Comment: @ReazMurshed nope 8bit screws the sound awfully up.... that should be 16bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this issue.
I actually initialized OpenSL twice and therefore also started to write to two concurrent bufferqueues from one source - this lead to half the frames not being properly played.